# How to sum a number in a list

Tags: haskell, lazylist

My question is :

I have a list and a number and I want to sum the number to the list so I can do this

```
Adding ls n = [x+n| x<-ls]
```

and it works.

My question is I want to add `n+1`, `n+2`, `n+3` depending of the  length of the list.

If I do

```
let b = 0
Adding´ ls n = [x+adder n b| x<-ls] where adder n b= n+b,b++
```

it doesn't work because the `b` doesn't advance, so if I have `Adding´ [1,3,4] 3 = [4,7,9]` .

Comment: `adding xs n = zipWith (+) xs [n..] = [x+i | (x,i) <- zip xs [n..]]`. is this what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`Data.List.mapAccumL`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:mapAccumL) (`mapAccumL :: Traversable t => (a -> b -> (a, c)) -> a -> t b -> (a, t c)`) to achieve this task.

The first parameter is a function which takes two parameters `a` (accumulator) and `n` (the list item) and returns a tuple. In our case we increment `a` (the accumulator) by 1 and map the current element `n` by adding the accumulator. The result is a tuple in which the first item is the final state of the accumulator and the second is the final state of the list. We extract the second item by `snd`.

```
Prelude> snd $ Data.List.mapAccumL (\a n -> (a+1,n+a)) 3 [1,3,4]
[4,7,9]
```

Comment: I cant use any modules i can only use the first 2 chapters of the " Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!"

Answer (score 1):

Approach the problem recursively. Add a number to the *first* element of the list, then recurse on the *tail* of the list with the next larger number. Repeat until you are out of numbers. Instead of incrementing `b`, you start a new function call in which `b` has a larger value.

```
adding [] _ = []
adding (x:xs) b = x + b : adding xs (b+1)
```

As an example, consider

```
adding [7, 10, 7, 5] 0 == 7 + 0 : adding [10, 7, 5] 1
                       == 7     : (10 + 1 : adding [7, 5] 2)
                       == 7     : 11      : (7 + 2 : adding [5] 3)
                       == 7     : 11      : 9      : (5 + 3 : adding [] 4)
                       == 7     : 11      : 9      : 8      : []
                       == [7, 11, 9, 8]
```

You can replace `0` with any starting value `n` in the initial call; the recursive call always increments it.